# How to introduce a delay between webrequests

Tags: webrequest

I'm making a plug-in for Chrome. How do I add a delay between web requests.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(

        function(details) {
          // I want every request to be delayed. example: 10 milisecond
          return {cancel: details.url.indexOf("://www.evil.com/") != -1};
        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ["blocking"]);
```

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem, I need to screen the user's onbeforerequest, running the URL by a remote server to see if it's on a ban list.

I'm thinking I'll redirect the user to a sort of hourglass page, then push on when the request comes back.

So in your case with an arbitrary ten seconds, you return redirectUrl: [placeholder extension page] and that page counts for ten seconds, then loads the page that was to be delayed.